# Merging IntelliJ with Gitlab

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have a bunch of source code on a group GitLab (university server) repository and I'm trying to connect it to IntelliJ without having much success. Whenever I try and clone it to IntelliJ it doesnt actually bring the code over, whether it be using the HTTPS or SSH key, and when I test the cloning, it says repository test failed as there wasnt an executable git file. Does anybody know how I can set it up so that it is easy enough to push and pull from the repository? I am using IntelliJ IDEA if that helps.

TIA

Edit: Using Windows 10 OS and I presume the Git CLI is installed as using University devices.

Comment: Do you have the git CLI installed? Also the used OS could be helpful to answer your question.

Comment: I've edited the original post :)

Comment: What about cloning via CLI and then opening the cloned folder with intellij. Now it should detect the version controlled folder